# What's an elegant and efficient way of "moving" a row value to the end and "shifting" the others left in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I need to create an instead of trigger that in a specific case of insert will "move" a row value "Type" to the end and left "shift" once the other row values to the right to compensate

Original Insert:

```
+----------+-----+------------+------------+---------+------------+---------+
|   Name   | Job |    Date    |   Salary   |   Age   | Department |  Type   |
+----------+-----+------------+------------+---------+------------+---------+
| John Doe |   4 | Accountant | 20-07-2014 | 1000.54 |         25 | Defense |
+----------+-----+------------+------------+---------+------------+---------+
```

Desired Output:

```
+----------+------------+------------+---------+-----+------------+------+
|   Name   |    Job     |    Date    | Salary  | Age | Department | Type |
+----------+------------+------------+---------+-----+------------+------+
| John Doe | Accountant | 20-07-2014 | 1000.54 |  25 | Defense    |    4 |
+----------+------------+------------+---------+-----+------------+------+
```

Comment: You don't move columns around in a table, this isn't Excel, you move row values from a column to another. And doing permutations in a table is a very bad idea and will hurt your performance in all possible ways.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? A field in a table is supposed to contain values with specific types, constraints, that have a specific business meaning. "moving" them around as if this was Excel means putting unrelated values in unrelated fields that may not even accept them.

Comment: Are you allowed to assume your table structures? As far as SQL Server cares, it is not so that `C < D`, so you'd have to explicitly specify what values to assign to which columns (`SET C = inserted.D, D = inserted.E, ...`) This gets clumsy fast, especially if all possible combinations have to be allowed, but SQL rather likes its static typing. You may want to consider representing your data differently, by turning columns to rows -- that makes this exercise far simpler.

Comment: Didn't you post this earlier? Why did you delete your prior question to post the exact same one again? I can't access my comment from before, but my previous point still stands `INSERT INTO T (Col1,Col2) VALUES (1,2);` and `INSERT INTO T (Col2,Col1) VALUES (2,1);` are exactly the same.

Comment: @Larnu The other I ilustrated the example incorrectly

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The reason is that there're several types of data being inserted in the table. One type that I can identify has an extra column, the "target" that I want to put to the end so that I don't have to take it into account in the integration solution. 
The files are originally of the type csv. And all the columns in this specific type are shifted once there because of the column "target" being before them.

Comment: @AntonioCraveiro that's *not* a valid reason. You can select the columns returned by any query. Just *don't* select the columns you don't want. If the tool you use can't use source queries or can't select specific columns (are you sure?) create a view with only the fields you want.

Comment: @AntonioCraveiro btw all ETL tools allow you to select columns and specify custom queries. SSIS certainly does. Bulk export tools like `bcp` also work with queries

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That would involve changing all the places that query this table. And what about the types of the variables for each column? They will all be wrong if I don't "shift" them back.

Comment: @AntonioCraveiro it's already wrong if you mix up data like that. You *can* have diffrerent types of **records** in a table. You **can't** have different types of data in a field. It sounds like there's an integration script (not tool, no tool makes such mistakes) that mixed up the data. This was bound to lead to serious problems sooner or later. Breaking the data, or worse, actually **loosing** data isn't going to fix the script

Comment: @AntonioCraveiro before you say "in real life", in real life integration and ETL jobs don't mix up data, precisely because it *won't* make anything easier. A database isn't a CSV or Excel file either. Each table is supposed to represent *one* relation or entity or rarely, a class of related entities. Fields are *fields* similar to C# properties and fields. They are supposed to contain *specific* data. In real life, ETL and integration jobs *clean up the data*, turn them into a format compatible with the target system and then transfer them.

Comment: @AntonioCraveiro you can create intermediate *staging* tables that to hold intermediate results before pushing them to the target system. This way you won't have to use the same columns for different things

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I edited the example to make it clearer. Originally i only had data without types. Now I have some data that has types and will come in a specific column. I was going to add a column type to the table and when I get data of this specific type treat it so the values match the right columns.

Comment: I suspect you're asking this question because you imported dirty data. The solution is to clean your data before importing.

Comment: @HongOoi Not dirty data, I want to have a table that holds more than one type of entity by using auxiliar columns. It's not pretty, but the right way of doing it requires a lot of changes to different solutions across several platforms. I don't think there's an elegant way of doing the trigger either. An "IF" followed by an extensive "insert" (columns) (values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER ReorderTrigger 
ON TableName INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS 
INSERT TableName (Name, Job, Date, Salary, Age, Department, Type) 
SELECT Name, [Date], Salary, Age, Department,[Type], Job 
FROM inserted
```

This assumes that the columns are all of interchangeable data types. I used NVARCHAR(10) to make the example work. You'll have to adjust this for your expected data. You can use [CONVERT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in many cases but I'm not sure what data types are being inserted or what data types your columns have so I can't advise you further on where exactly to put the CONVERT functions.

An example might be

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, Salary, 103)
```

Which would make your trigger look like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ReorderTrigger ON TableName INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
INSERT TableName (Name, Job, Date, Salary, Age, Department, Type)
SELECT Name, [Date], CONVERT(DATETIME, Salary, 103), Age, Department,[Type], 
Job
FROM inserted
```

You can study how triggers work at [Create Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [Use the Inserted and Deleted Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-2017)